# Distinct latest versions in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, version, distinct

I have a column in my mysql table something like this:

appVersion

> ```
> 5.16.0.2889
> 5.16.0.2893
> 5.14.0
> 5.14.0.3
> 5.12.0.1
> 5.15.0.14
> 5.1.0.2
> 5.12.0.3
> ```

I want to get the distinct latest versions of this column segregated on the basis of the first two numbers (a.b.c.d then only consider a.b as a single version)

like here we have let’s say the 3 distinct latest versions would be:

```
5.16.0.2893
5.16.0.2889
5.15.0.14
5.14.0.3
5.14.0
```

can someone please suggest mysql query for this?

definition of latest:
let’s say if we have

```
5.14.0.9
5.12.0.4
6.1.0.2
5.14.0.12
5.16.1.2
5.12.1.1
```

distinct latest 3 would be

```
6.1.0.2
5.16.1.2
5.14.0.12
5.14.0.9
```

Comment: Define 'latest'

Comment: let's say if we have 
>    5.14.0.9
>    5.12.0.4
>    6.1.0.2
>    5.14.0.12
>    5.16.1.2
>    5.12.1.1

latest 4 would be
>    6.1.0.2
>    5.16.1.2
>    5.14.0.12
>    5.14.0.9

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: The two examples are a bit different. The new one can be solved very simply, but if the original one is really plausible, then we have to be a bit more inventive.

Comment: yeah, sorry, edited it now

Comment: I see in your sample data a value `5.14.0`. What is the difference with a value like `5.14.0.0`? Also what is your MySql version?

Comment: @forpas there's no difference between 5.14.0 and 5.14.0.0, both are same
mysql version - 5.7.29

Comment: Do you always have max 4 parts in the version number? Just convert it to 4 numbers and sort it starting from the left most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand from your question, you need to display 3 latest "a.b" kind of versions, but with all it's subversions. Here is the code that will work :

```
     select ver from app inner join 
  (select CONCAT(LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ver, '.', 1), 50, '0'),
LPAD(SUBSTRING(ver, LOCATE('.', ver)+1, LOCATE('.', ver, LOCATE('.', ver)+1)), 50, '0')) as ver2
from app group by ver2 order by ver2 desc limit 3) as v2 
on CONCAT(LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ver, '.', 1), 50, '0'),
LPAD(SUBSTRING(ver, LOCATE('.', ver)+1, LOCATE('.', ver, LOCATE('.', ver)+1)), 50, '0')) = v2.ver2 
order by v2.ver2 desc
```

The inner query spits out the top 3 versions of the form 'a.0000b', and the inner join matches all the versions to 'a.b' = 'c.d'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT VersNo
FROM (
SELECT  DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(appVersion,'.',2) AS 'VersionNo',appVersion AS 'VersNo'
FROM table
ORDER BY appVersion)s
ORDER BY VersNo;
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, this will make it more accessible.